Is there any way to get name of intent flag in Android?
I wondered if Android has a way to get the name of an intent flag. For instance I get flag value by method intent.flags but these are just int value. I found that 524288 is const value of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but don't find out the way to get the flag name. Anyone know the way to archive it? Thanks.

Since the documentation doesn't explain this, let me do it here:
intent.flags is a combination of flag values (which are powers of 2), that is produced by doing a bitwise OR operation (FLAG_FOO | FLAG_BAR).
You are supposed to check if a specific flag is present by doing a bitwise AND operation (intent.flags && FLAG_FOO != 0).

even when you "split" intent.flags for separated ints for every flag - how to print those not as numbers? this is what op needs as I understand... so he want to print e.g. in log "FLAG_FOO=true, FLAG_BAR=false, FLAG_SOME_OTHER=false" - probably preferable all flags which may be placed and are present in intent.flags

Thank for your idea. I may need it to extract flag values from intent. But my need is prints the flag values in their name in string and as snachmsm said it is impossible :((

Sorry, I didn't see "printing" mentioned in the question. Check out this piece of code: https://gist.github.com/joecks/4559331

I've deleted my answer, as above comment is probably exactly what op needs and I was looking for smth like this some time ago without luck. Thanks!!
